# Adal library for China specific azure cloud

Tags: azure, adal

I am working on a single page application that uses adal.js for Authentication with AAD. Now we are also planning to deploy this application in China specific Azure cloud.

What confuses me is a hardcoded(may be done by my collegues) link in adal.js file at line 112, as shown below.

```
   if (AuthenticationContext.prototype._singletonInstance) {
    return AuthenticationContext.prototype._singletonInstance;
}
AuthenticationContext.prototype._singletonInstance = this;

// public
this.instance = 'https://login.windows.net/';
this.config = {};
this.callback = null;
this.popUp = false;

// private
this._user = null;
this._renewActive = false;
this._loginInProgress = false;
this._renewStates = [];

    This address 'https://login.windows.net/' isn't valid for azure china cloud.
```

So do i need to change this value in code or we have any new version of ADAl where this login address need not be changed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you try using `https://login.chinacloudapi.cn/` instead of `https://login.windows.net/`?

Comment: Hi Gaurav thanks for the answer. But my question is : is there an uri which would redirect to correct endpoint depending on where the application is deployed? That way we will not have to change this uris for every new regional cloud(heard that they are coming up with other regional clouds).

Answer (score 2):

As @GauravMantri said, the difference for using Azure AD between Global Azure and China Azure is only using different endpoints, please see the figure below which be snapshotted from China Azure portal.

[image]

As reference, here is some variables (in C#) required for China Azure AD.

```
private static string clientId = "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx";
private static string appKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=";
private static string graphResourceId = "https://graph.chinacloudapi.cn";
private static string domainName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.partner.onmschina.cn";
private static string tenantID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
```

For using `adal.js`, you can try to search in the source code and replace these endpoints for global with them for China Azure. Or I think that you can try to refer to the global Azure AD REST API with China Azure endpoints to verify whether the difference is just within endpoints, and to use REST API in your code.

Meanwhile, there is a document which lists the endpoints mapping between global and china, please move to the url https://www.azure.cn/documentation/articles/developerdifferences/#bookmark-7 (the section name at the right sidebar is `中国区 Azure 资源端点URI (供应用程序代码使用)`) if you could read in chinese.

I snapshot the figure below about Azure AD.
[image]

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.